# Concatenar 2 valores de un objeto con un espacio

Tags: javascript

```javascript
var dueño =  {"apellido": "Medina", "nombre": "Nicky"}.
```

Necesito retornar el nombre concatenado con el apellido: "Nicky Medina". El problema está en que los tengo que retornar con un espacio de por medio, y no encuentro la forma de generar el espacio, me sale solo `NickyMedina`

Comment: Lee [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para tener consejos al buscar ayuda en el sitio, el codigo que tengas debe ir formateado para mostrarse como tal.

Comment: El espacio se genera asi: `' '` o también asi: `" "`. Cuál es el problema?

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar cadenas literales para concatenar:

```js
var dueño = {"apellido": "Medina", "nombre": "Nicky"}

function getFullName(person){
  return `${person.nombre} ${person.apellido}`
}

console.log(getFullName(dueño))
```